# Android UiAutomator detecting WebView elements outside device area

Tags: android, android-webview, appium, android-uiautomator

I am currently working on automation testing on hybrid apps using appium. While running the tests, I noticed that the elements of the navigation bar on some pages are being detected outside the device area in Android UiAutomator. This also makes any commands operating on the elements in this region fail. We can't detect the element via xPath and can't click on it. I've attached a screenshot showing the way the elements are detected.

[image]

Is this a bug in UiAutomator? If so, is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Is your navigation bar part of the webview ? if it is part of the webview, UIAutomatorviewer fails to map the correct co-ordinates unless its a native app.

Comment: @Vinayak : Thanks Vinayak. Can you please explain why this happens? Or is there some documentation or reference I can go through to get a better idea?

Comment: It happens if your application is a webview. To confirm, launch the chrome browser, inspect device and check if you can inspect elements from there. If you find the webview session, you should switch to webview from appium and tap on button.

Comment: But the whole page is a webview. the navigation bar is a part of the same webview. Why does it alone get mapped differently?

Comment: Webviews are meant to be accessed from the chromedriver / chromebrowser not from uiautoamator. UIAutomator might make an educated guess, but the mapping may not be correct always for all the items.